# Session cache duplicate column name: expires in

Tags: python, sqlite, python-requests

I am using a SQLite request cache but following code snippet raises an error:

```py
session = requests_cache.CachedSession(cache_name='my_cache_name', expire_after=3600)    
response = session.get(url=url, headers=request_headers)
```

> **Error :** sqlite3.OperationalError: duplicate column name: expires